# Ligdx Unable to position images in Stack

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#overlapping-widgets) to have overlapping widgets the `Stack` should be used.

However, I could not find how to position the widgets inside the stack relative to each other. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a panel, where the players position is shown on top of a mini-map of the scene.

How can the actors inside the Stack positioned? Is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around in the sourcecde a bit, it became clear why `Stack` didn't let any modification to size and position: [it overwrites it](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/ef99e626bb5a991463b4b1678bdaa34a4f3ec5e4/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.java#L106).

So since `Stack` Extends `WidgetGroup` I tried to use it, instead of `Stack` and the positioning actually works.

```java
minimap_border = new Image(used_skin.getRegion("panel"));
minimap_border.setFillParent(false);
minimap_border.setFillParent(true);
minimap = new Image();
minimap.setSize(120,120);
minimap.setPosition(4,4);
WidgetGroup minimapStack = new WidgetGroup();
minimapStack.addActor(minimap_border);
minimapStack.addActor(minimap);
```